# Adding description for Record type data in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Currently I have this column with record type namely items. It have another columns such as items.id (string), items.name (string), and items.price (float64).

I would like to add description such as :

1. items.id : Unique id of an item
2. items.name : Name of an item
3. items.price : The original price for an item

I tried to use Alter table and alter column method, but it seems it doesn't allow me to achieve this. My queries look like this :

```
ALTER TABLE
  `table_a` ALTER COLUMNS items.id
SET
  OPTIONS (description = "Unique id of an item"),
 ALTER COLUMNS items.name
  SET
    OPTIONS (description = "Name of an item")
```

But it raise me an error of :

Syntax error : Unexpected '.'

Any suggestion will greatly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: you need to close the double quotes. but i don't think you can add description to those, why not change the descripion of the column?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your query, I believe a column name with "." is not acceptable with BQ, Reference: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#column_names

> A column name can contain the letters (a-z, A-Z), numbers (0-9), or underscores (_), and it must start with a letter or underscore

Query works fine assuming with a dataset named "items" :

```
ALTER TABLE
  items.`table_a` ALTER COLUMN id
SET
  OPTIONS (description = "Unique id of an item"),
  ALTER COLUMN name
SET
  OPTIONS (description = "Name of an item")
```

Comment: Hi! I've tried your solutions, but it seems it still has an error on my end

Comment: Hello!, Is it still the same error ?